# JOIN multiple tables with WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a master table (Project List) along with several sub tables that are joined on one common field (RecNum). I need to get totals for all of the sub tables, by column and am not sure how to do it. This is a sample of the table design. There are more columns in each table but I'm showing a sampling of the column names and values to get an idea of what to do.

```
Project List
| RecNum |
|      6 |

WeekA
| RecNum | UserName | Day1Reg | Day1OT | Day2Reg | Day2OT | Day3Reg | Day3OT |
|      6 | JustMe   |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |       5 |      6 |
|      6 | NotMe    |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |       5 |      6 |

WeekB
| RecNum | UserName | Day1Reg | Day1OT | Day2Reg | Day2OT | Day3Reg | Day3OT |
|      6 | JustMe   |       7 |      8 |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |
|      6 | NotMe    |       7 |      8 |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |
```

So the first query should return the complete totals for both users, like this:

```
| sumDay1Reg | sumDay1OT | sumDay2Reg | sumDay2OT | sumDay3Reg | sumDay3OT |
|         16 |        20 |          8 |        12 |         16 |        20 |
```

The second query should return the totals for just a specified user, (WHERE UserName = 'JustMe') like this:

```
| sumDay1Reg | sumDay1OT | sumDay2Reg | sumDay2OT | sumDay3Reg | sumDay3OT |
|          8 |        10 |          4 |         6 |          8 |        10 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to have multiple tables that store the same kind of data; you should have a single `Weeks` table that has an additional column for the week.

Anyway, the easiest way to handle this table structure is to combine the tables first:

```
SELECT SUM(Day1Reg) AS sumDay1Reg,
       SUM(Day10T)  AS sumDay10T,
       ...
FROM (SELECT * FROM WeekA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM WeekB)
WHERE userName = 'JustMe'  -- optional
```

Comment: Thanks CL. Yeah, I know about the multiple tables issue and am in the process of rebuilding the app to use a single table. But in the meantime I've got to work with what I've been given. The only thing I don't see here is matching by RecNum. So in "Project List" we have multiple RecNum's and I want the sums for each RecNum in the WeekX tables. I thought there would be a "LEFT JOIN" in there somewhere, just not sure where.

Comment: Changed the layout to show better what I need in the end.

Comment: Do not change the question to something different. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Anyway, the subquery can be treated like a table.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess it is pretty different than originally asked. I'll accept yours as correct and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  (SUM(a.Day1Reg + b.Day1Reg)) AS sumDay1Reg,
  (SUM(a.Day1OT + b.Day1OT)) AS sumDay1OT,
  (SUM(a.Day2Reg + b.Day2Reg)) AS sumDay2Reg,
  (SUM(a.Day2OT + b.Day2OT)) AS sumDay2OT,
  (SUM(a.Day3Reg + b.Day3Reg)) AS sumDay3Reg,
  (SUM(a.Day3OT + b.Day3OT)) AS sumDay3OT
FROM WeekA a,
     WeekB b
WHERE a.userName = 'JustMe' AND b.userName = 'JustMe' --Comment this out for first query
```